# Call namedQuery inside a criteria in controller

Tags: grails, criteria, named-query

Is possible to call namedQuery on grails inside a controller? I know that I can call a namedQuery inside another namedQuery, but i dont want to do that. Any ideas? Thanks

**User**.groovy

```
static namedQueries = {
      filterUsers{
            eq("age", 21)
      }
}
```

**MyController**.groovy

```
def r = User.createCriteria().list {
     eq("id", 1)
     filterUsers() //not possible
}
```

or..

**MyController**.groovy

```
    //not possible too
    //Cannot invoke method createCriteria() on null object

    def r = User.filterUsers().createCriteria().list {
         eq("id", 1)           
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example:

**Domain:**

```
class User {

    int age
    String userName

    static namedQueries = {
        filterUsers {
            eq("age", 21)
        }
    }

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
class TestController {

    def index = {

        def users = User.filterUsers {
            and {
                like 'userName', 'Derek%'
            }
        }

        render users as JSON
    }
}
```

Also, you can find more about this here: [Reference Documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/namedQueries.html)